# Modify original email message in custom email service

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

I'm writing an email service and want to save a header value to `EmailMessage` object (custom field). 
As I understand the process is:
New inbound email > Email Service is called > Email is inserted to database as `EmailMessage` object

Maybe I'm missing something, but:

1. how to update saved `EmailMessage` object from email service? e.g. I've extracted some info from header and want to save value as custom field
2. is the email message inserted before or after calling email services?

Moreover I couldn't find any `Id` or reference to `EmailMessage` object

here's my code:

**main:**

```
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail em, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env) {

        em.myCustomField__c = extractHeader('some-header'); // variable doesn't exist, can't update

        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
        return result;
}
```

Comment: `EmailMessage` object is used exclusively for Email to Case (which does not use inbound email services) so you may need to clarify your objective.

Comment: @cropredy I've updated description, basically I will also have to handle creation of `EmailMessage` myself, right? It isn't inserted automatically as with email to case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel as if you may need to rethink your objective

1. InboundEmailServices will never receive `EmailMessage`.
2. (prior to Summer 16), `EmailMessage` is used exclusively for Email2Case and is always a child of `Case`. Post summer 16, the Enhanced Email feature allows for using `EmailMessage` for all emails sent from SFDC. See [Considerations in Help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=emailadmin_enhanced_email_considerations.htm&language=en_US)
3. (prior to Summer 16) `EmailMessage` is not customizable with additional fields. Post summer 16, the Enhanced Email feature allows for customization

So, if you are receiving emails to some address `foo@mycompany.com` that are being forwarded by your mail server to the configured Force.com EmailServices address (which in turn invokes an Inbound Email Services Handler), then:

1. The received email will not go into `EmailMessage`. Programmatically trying to put it there is nonsensical since that sobject is reserved for Email2Case.
2. You will need to save the headers/body in an object(s). [The documentation shows an example](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com) with `Account` + `Attachments` + `Note`